# Using JavaScript Functions to Manipulate HTML

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm having a spot of trouble in making my functions work and my book seems to be pure rubbish. I'm sure that the error is purely syntax, although it may be something more.

Here is the JavaScript that I've written. Obviously the banner function doesn't provide full functionality, but it *should* do *something.* Currently I just get a broken image link.

```
function displayBanner(currentDate) {
    var imgSrc = defaultLogo;
    if  (currentDate.getMonth() == 1)
        imgSrc = "winterLogo";
    return ("<img src='" + imgSrc + ".gif'>");
}


function calcDaysToSale(currentDate) {
    var saleDay = new Date();
    saleDay.setDate(15);    // sets the sale date to the 15th of the current month

    // Subtracts the days remaining until the sale.
    // If the number is negative, the sale is over.
    var Days = saleDay.getDate()-currentDate.getDate();
    if (Days < 0) {
        return "The sale has ended.";
    }
    else {
        return Days;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm thinking that the reason for this is that it isn't being called correctly. Here is the function I've embedded in the head of the html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageSetup() {
          var today = new Date(); // this creates a date object with today's date
          var banner = displayBanner(today); // *should* call the displayBanner     function
      
          var days = calcDaysToSale(today); // *should* call the function using today's date
          document.sale.saleMessage.value = days; // *should* set the value to days.
      
      // Obviously none of it works.
      
    }

 </script>
```

I call `pageSetup()` at the bottom of my page. I posted the full html code below.

This may be, and I'm pretty sure it is, purely a syntax problem. However, the things that I've thought to Google and look up in my book haven't led me to any answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Carol's Flowers</title>
<link href="flowers.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="flowers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageSetup() {
          var today = new Date(); // this creates a date object with today's date
          var banner = displayBanner(today); // *should* call the displayBanner function
          
          var days = calcDaysToSale(today); // *should* call the function using today's date
          document.sale.saleMessage.value = days; // *should* set the value to days.
          
          // Obviously none of it works.
          
        }

     </script>

</head>

<body  class="oneColLiqCtrHdr">

<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <p><img name="myBanner" src="banner" id="myBanner" alt="Carol's Flowers" />
      <!-- end #header -->
    </p>
    <div id="links"><a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">General Arrangements</a> | <a href="#">Seasonal Designs</a> | <a href="#">Custom Orders</a> | <a href="#">Location</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <table id="mainTable">
    <tr>
       <td width="201"><h1><img src="Flowers.JPG" alt="Random Flowers" width="200" height="255" /></h1></td>
       <td width="687">
    <p>Here at Carol's Flowers, we believe that there is a perfect floral arrangment for every occasion! Take a look around and see if there is anything you like. If we don't already have it, then we will create it for you!</p></td>
    </script>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p> <form name="sale" id="sale">
      Days Until Mid Month Madness Sale : 
      <input type="text" name="saleMessage" id="saleMessage" /></form></p>
    <!-- end #footer --></div>
<!-- end #container --></div>

<!-- I am trying to run the script here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    pageSetup();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know that the `displayBanner()` function is not getting called? You assign the result to a variable, `banner`, and then don't use that variable at all. The function itself returns a _string_ with the markup for an img, it doesn't actually add an img element to your document. (Where is `defaultLogo` defined?)

Comment: It would probably help if I posted the html code. I think that I've handled those issues in there..although that *may* be my problem. I'm rather new to web design. However, what I've done for this seemed to work in a previous project but not in this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `displayBanner` function looks fine, but make sure of the following:

- The html string it returns is actually added to the document correctly. Post your code of how you do this if you're not sure.
- the variable `defaultLogo` is defined.
- The string you end up using for the src of the image is valid URL that goes to the image you want.

You set the variable banner to contain the html src returned from the displayBanner function, but you don't actually do anything with it in the code you've posted. Try adding

```
document.write( displayBanner(today) );
```

to the html document where you want the image to appear for a quick fix, or put this somewhere in your javascript, using the id of the element you want the image to appear inside.

```
document.getElementById("desired_element_id").innerHTML = displayBanner(today);
```

For the other part, again your function looks fine, just make sure you're applying it correctly to the document. Try adding this to your pageSetup function.

```
document.getElementById("saleMessage").value = days;
```

EDIT: I just tested your code. Make sure you're actually including the 'flowers.js' file by putting some alerts in it and seeing if they show up when you open the main document. Also, I still can't find anywhere where 'defaultLogo' is defined, so that could be causing your image src problem.

Comment: Looking back, it is saying that `defaultLogo` is not defined. The logos are in the same directory as the code, and it should be returning the value of `defaultLogo.gif`, right? It is a Uncaught ReferenceError.

Also, the `document.getElementById("saleMessage").value = days;` does not seem to add the number. I'm new to web design, but not coding. I don't know what the problem with getting the days would be..

Comment: How would I put an alert in? I'm not sure what I would put that would show up on the page..I hadn't even considered that the script might not be included.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("saleMessage").value = 4`, which is currently working for me, although I did put the javascript functions from flower.js in the first script tag. After that, replace the literal 4 with `calcDaysToSale( new Date() );`. As to your other question, the variable defaultLogo won't contain anything unless you set it yourself, so you need to actually hardcode a string somewhere. From what you've said, you probably meant `var imgSrc = "defaultLogo;"`, with quotation marks if you're trying to access the image 'defaultLogo.gif' :D

Comment: @Linell If you add `alert("It's working!")` to flowers.js outside of any function, it will be run when the script it loaded, which should give you a little pop-up window that has the argument string inside of it.

Comment: That is very useful! Thank you! It is in fact working, and I've got the days until the sale working fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably just that the img URL isn't being found.  Check in firebug what the URL is being resolved to.  Probably just not hitting the right path on the server.

Does the URL in firebug show it returns an image?  Does the image URL ever get requested at all?

Also - you are using the `<img>` markup somewhere, right?  (See nnnnn's comment)

You would want to do something like:

```
var banner = displayBanner(today);
document.getElementById('myPlaceholder').innerHTML = banner;
```

But since you say there is a broken image visible, the issue is probably just the URL not resolving correctly.

For a local page, you could right click the broken image and check its URL.

Comment: You are indeed correct that the URL isn't as it should be. The URL is coming back as `file:///Users/Linell/dropbox/Code/Tutorial.02/banner`. Shouldn't this line `<img name="myBanner" src="banner" id="myBanner" alt="Carol's Flowers" />` combined with the code that you suggested make the banner work?

I'm also having trouble making the countdown until the sale work, although I suspect that once I figure out making the banner appear I'll understand that problem.

Comment: How is the URL wrong?  What should it be?  Probably you are just not getting the path root you expect.

Comment: It should be the name of the image file, right? Something like `file:///Users/Linell/dropbox/Code/Tutorial.02/winterLogo.gif`. Or am I thinking of that in the wrong way?

Comment: Is `banner` the name of the image when its not winter?  In the Tutorial.02 dir, are the images there?  It looks like the .gif is not displayed sometimes.

Comment: The name of the image when it isn't winter should be defaultLogo.gif..banner is the name of the variable that I assigned to it.

Yes, the images are in the directory.

Comment: OK.  Can you post the line of JS code where you make use of this `"<img src='" + imgSrc + ".gif'>"`?  If that img src is still just 'banner' it probably never got changed.   Also, just before that line, do either `console.log('imgSrc='+imgSrc');` or `alert(imgSrc)`

Comment: `alert(imgSrc)` yields winterLogo. `console.log('imgSrc='+imgSrc');` yields a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Working on same problem, did several hours of work but still need help.*/



<script type="text/javascript" src="flowers.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var calcDaysToSale = new Date(); 
var displayBanner= getBanner(); 
var days = calcDaysToSale(); 

document.getElementById("Banner").innerHTML = displayBanner(today);
document.getElementById("saleMessage").value = days;
</script>

</head>
<body >

<div id="Banner">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<img id='Banner" src='Banner"+bannerNum+".gif' alt='' />")

</script>
</div>

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<p><img name="myBanner" src="banner" id="myBanner" alt="Carol's Flowers" />
 <!-- end #header -->
</p>
<div id="links"><a href="#">
Home
</a> 
| <a href="#">General Arrangements
</a> 
<a href="#">Seasonal Designs
</a>| 
<a href="#">Custom Orders
</a>
|<a href="#">Location
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
<table id="mainTable">
<tr>
<td width="201">
<h1>
<img src="Flowers.JPG" alt="Random Flowers" width="200" height="255" />
</h1>
</td>
<td width="687">
<p>Here at Carol's Flowers, we believe that there is a perfect floral arrangement for every occasion! Take a look around and see if there is anything you like. If we don't already have it, then we will create it for you!
</p>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
<!-- end #mainContent -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <p>
 <form name="sale" id="sale">
```

Days Until Mid Month Madness Sale :

```
</body>
```

Comment: Im not sure there is too much wrong with just showing your code. just be aware that some people get very ticky about having a post that looks like a "code dump".

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Javascript potion*/




Function List:
displayBanner(currentDate)
Using the date, sets the banner image source
calcDaysToSale(currentDate)
Returns the days to sale message
*/

//display the current month from date
document.clockform.monthnow. value="99";
document.clockform.datenow. value="99";

function Banner(currentDate) 
{

var imgSrc = Banner1;
if  (currentDate.getMonth() == 2)
    imgSrc = "Banner5";

if  (currentDate.getMonth() ==7 )
    imgSrc = "Banner4";

 if  (currentDate.getMonth() == 3)
    imgSrc = "Banner3";

if  (currentDate.getMonth() == 10)
    imgSrc = "Banner2";

return ("<img  src='Banner"+bannerNum+".gif' >");
}

function calcDaysToSale(currentDate)
 {
var saleDay = new Date();
saleDay.setDate(15);   

var Days = saleDay.getDate()-currentDate.getDate();

if (Days < 0) 
{
return ("The sale has ended.");
}
else
 {
return Days;
}
}
```